# symfony2 custom_provider

Tags: symfony, propel

I have been trying to follow this example from propel to configure a custom security provider

http://www.propelorm.org/cookbook/symfony2/the-symfony2-security-component-and-propel.html

however I always get this error

```
ServiceNotFoundException: The service "security.authentication.manager" has a dependency on a non-existent service "acme.secured.security.provider"
```

It appears not to be loading the services.xml but I cannot be sure. Has anyone else come across a similar issue? Im new to symfony2, can anyone suggest the best place to start debugging this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So import it. In your app/config.yml:

```
imports:
    acme_bundle:
        resource: "@AcmeSecuredBundle/Resources/config/services.xml"
```

You can read more about importing services in [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#importing-other-container-configuration-resources).

Comment: Thank you that did the trick. I even started to read that page should probably have kept reading. rtfm next time.